# "Invalid argument" While executing a command from python using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, yt-dlp

I want to execute a command from python. This is the original command:

```
yt-dlp -f bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best --downloader ffmpeg --downloader-args "ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:19:10.00 -to 00:19:40.00" --no-check-certificate https://youtu.be/YXfnjrbmKiQ
```

So I am doing this:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.call(['yt-dlp','-f','bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best','--downloader','ffmpeg','--downloader-args','"ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:00:10.00 -to 00:00:40.00"','--no-check-certificate','https://youtu.be/YXfnjrbmKiQ'])

print(result)
```

But it gives me the error:

```
ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:00:10.00 -to 00:00:40.00: Invalid argument
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Incidentally, the linked duplicate is someone making the exact same mistake _also_ with video download/encoding tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run without `shell=True` then you don't need `" "` in element `'"ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:00:10.00 -to 00:00:40.00"'` because normally only `shell` need it to recognize which element keep as one string - but later `shell` sends this string to system without `" "`

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.call([
    'yt-dlp', 
    '-f', 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best'
    '--downloader', 'ffmpeg'
    '--downloader-args', 'ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:19:10.00 -to 00:19:40.00'
    '--no-check-certificate',
    'https://youtu.be/YXfnjrbmKiQ'
])

print(result)
```

OR you could run it with `shell=True` and then you need single string and you have to use `" "`

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.call(
   'yt-dlp -f bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best --downloader ffmpeg --downloader-args "ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:19:10.00 -to 00:19:40.00" --no-check-certificate https://youtu.be/YXfnjrbmKiQ',
   shell=True
)

print(result)
```

---

**BTW:**

There is standard module `shlex` which can convert string with command to list of arguments.

```
import shlex

cmd = 'yt-dlp -f bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best --downloader ffmpeg --downloader-args "ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:19:10.00 -to 00:19:40.00" --no-check-certificate https://youtu.be/YXfnjrbmKiQ'

cmd = shlex.split(cmd)

print(cmd)
```

Result shows this element without `" "`:

```
['yt-dlp', 
'-f', 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best', 
'--downloader', 'ffmpeg', 
'--downloader-args', 'ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:19:10.00 -to 00:19:40.00', 
'--no-check-certificate', 'https://youtu.be/YXfnjrbmKiQ']
```